# With WinDbg, can I modify an item in memory while a process is running?

Tags: debugging, windbg

Can I, using an address found in a map file, use windbg to alter a variable in memory while the app is running?

I'm really interested in turning on/off functionality in run-time maybe with a variable.

How would you do this? Does it require breaking the app through the debugger?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the address, you can use the any of the e* (Enter Value) commands.

You can attach to any running process if you know the process id, or you can launch the exe directly with cdb.  You do have to break the process to make any modifications.  In CDB, you can use Ctrl+C, and the it will inject a DebugBreak into the process, you can then look at the stack, threads, and memory.

Comment: Yes, you can, you can attach to the process with cdb if you know the processID.  And if you have the mapfile, you can peek at any address range and poke at any the memory locations.

Comment: But correct me if i wrong you can't executed any command while application is running (at least with drivers) you must break and only after program stops you can do something.

Answer (score 1):

I just did it.  Assuming you got the symbos mapped, and are in a breakpoint where you can see a variable, you just do this - assuming "myvar" is an integer:

?? myvar
   [[ this shows the current contents ]]

?? myvar=55
   [[ this will change the value of myvar to 55]]

?? myvar
   [[ this will show the updated contents of my var - which is 55 ]]

g
   [[ your program will now run, and the next read of myvar will produce 55 ]]

Answer (score 1):

You can set a breakpoint that is only hit once and edit a value and continue execution.
Something like:

```
bp /1 012ABCDEF "myVar=42;g"
```

replace the above with your address value and your variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure  what exactly you trying to achieve, but debugger should be activated on some event (exception, break point or something), after it's activated, for example you can have a thread that create an exception and after get control back check the variable.
In debugger you can set a break point with command, see [this guide](http://software.rkuster.com/windbg/WinDBG_A_to_Z.pdf), what will change the parameter.
I hope that this answer your question, if not please clarify the question.

In case of break point with command the application will be break and will continue execution without human intervention, i don't know any way how debugger can do something without application stops execution.

Just a thought, are you sure you need debugger for this? Can't you just use registry for that and use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724892(VS.85).aspx) to get notification about registry change.

Answer (score 0):

You can definately do that.  Either break on a function and edit it in the locals window.  Or use e commands to edit values.  Check out the windbg help for more on it.